# Calendar events time show TIME and GMT+N

Tags: calendar, macos, ical

Why my calendar shows local time **AND** GMT+N hours? How can I get rid of this `GMT+N` addition?

In the red box you can see how time of events is displayed in my calendar.
Below is the part of System Preferences > Language & Region > Advanced Tab settings.

I tried to turn Time Zone Support On and Off - no difference.

macOS version Sierra 10.12.1

[image]

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: Currently it is CET (Central European Time), UTC/GMT +1 hour. We've switched one hour back yesterday. Before yesterday it was GMT + 2.

Comment: So GMT+2 is the correct timezone for the time you tool the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, this is right.